# Error while running spring mvc as standalone app using embedded jetty

Tags: spring-mvc, embedded-jetty, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a main class to run spring mvc application as standalone application using jetty. I used maven-shade-plugin to generate the jar file.

I see the following error when i run the jar file

```
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$1: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 106; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

My mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">
```

Can any one help me what is missing

Comment: If your listing is the complete XML, then there needs to be a </beans> or <beans xmlns... />.

Comment: That was just a snippet of my mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 1):

It worked by adding the below in maven-shade-plugin configuration

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
```